# linux apache localhost now not accessible in LAN

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, opensuse

using Mediawiki in VMware localhost on (virtual) OpenSuse computer (latest version of distro) in company domain. MediaWiki using sqlite database. I had long latency (slow response) in localhost and also in company's network, so I tried first advice found through Google:

in **/etc/hosts** change:

*127.0.0.1 localhost*

to

*127.0.0.1:8080 localhost*

after restarting server, I cannot already access localhost of this computer (on other company's PC via internet browser, url address is ip address of computer with OpenSuse). Localy (on OpenSuse´s) localhost works fine.

So, I tried to revert this change (removing :8080) and restart server again, but accessing issue is still there. Also tried **/etc/init.d/network restart** command.

Comment: Firstly, make sure there is a tab between the IP address of 127.0.0.1 and the name localhost. Secondly - if you run "ping localhost", does it resolve to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Adam Thompson: yes, it it tab character between these two items (no spaces). And localhost is accessible on OpenSuse (also ping, yes resolving 127.0.0.1), but on another computer in company´s network now not.

Comment: I might be missing something here. On your OpenSuse computer, you can access the Mediawiki site by going to http://127.0.0.1:8080/, but you can't access it from another computer by going to http://192.168.123.123:8080/ (assuming 192.168.123.123 is the IP of the OpenSuse server)?

Comment: in browser on OpenSuse (localy):

127.0.0.1 - OK  

127.0.0.1:8080 - unable to connect  

localhost - OK  

on another PC in company's network:  

192.168.109.204 - timeout  

192.168.109.204:8080 - timeout  

Before changing etc/hosts file connection works!

Comment: So your OpenSuse server is listening on port 80, and not 8080. If you're running MediaWiki on Apache, check the listenaddress is set to the proper IP of the OpenSuse server, and not 127.0.0.1

Comment: Please provide me more info about where are stored listened ports (config file). I spend one hour on Google and can't find this information.
edit: It is strange, that before editing /etc/hosts it works and I just write :8080 :-(